# Remote image in Qt SVG?

Tags: qt, svg

How can I include an image from the Internet within SVG that Qt will display?
I keep getting the error:

```
couldn't create image from  "http://www.colorwiki.com/images/2/22/Lindbloom.jpg"
```

SVG:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image xlink:href="http://www.colorwiki.com/images/2/22/Lindbloom.jpg" x="0" y="0"
      height="100" width="100" />
</svg>
```

If the image is local, this works - it just fails for remote images.

Comment: Use the QtWebKit/QtWebEngine APIs?

Comment: @peppe good idea - just a bit worried that might be over-engineering considering I just want to lazy-load images in a stylised cell (it's for a list of video search results).  I think my options might be (a) fetching them myself before SVG rendering, QtQuick or WebEngine - unless I'm missing some simpler way?

Comment: You need to fetch the remote image to a temporary file, and reference that file in the svg. Or, if the svg component supports image providers, do the same to memory and supply the image through the provider.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rewrite a Class inherited from QtextBrowser, The Follow is my solution:
Header File:

```
#ifndef QHTMLBROWSER_H
#define QHTMLBROWSER_H 

#include <QtNetwork/QtNetwork>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QHash>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QCryptographicHash>
#include <QApplication>

class QHtmlBrowser : public QTextBrowser
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QHtmlBrowser(QWidget *parent=0);
    ~QHtmlBrowser();

    void load(const QString &strHtml);
    void addResource(const QString& key, const QByteArray& bytes);
    void showHtml(const QString& strHtml, int timeoutSeconds);

signals:
    void loadFinished();

private:
    QString mHtml;
    QHash<QString, QByteArray> mResources;

public slots:
    void onLoadFinished();


};

#endif // QHTMLBROWSER_H
```

Cpp File:

```
#include "qhtmlbrowser.h"
#include <QtGui/QVBoxLayout>
#include "globalsetting.h"
/*only provide the function GlobalSetting::getServer(),
   full url like :  http://www.colorwiki.com
*/


#define hit_ext(p) \
    else if (src.endsWith(#p, Qt::CaseInsensitive)) \
        ext = #p

#define index_tag   "question"
#define images_tag   "http://"

QString setUrl(QUrl& parentUrl, const QString& path)
{
    QString srcUrl;
    QString hostPath = parentUrl.host();
    if (parentUrl.port() != 80 && parentUrl.port()>0)
        hostPath += ":" + QString::number(parentUrl.port());
    hostPath += parentUrl.path();
    int pos = hostPath.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (pos > -1)
        hostPath = hostPath.left(pos);
    srcUrl = hostPath + "/" + path;
    while (srcUrl.contains("//"))
        srcUrl.replace("//", "/");
    srcUrl = "http://" + srcUrl;
    return srcUrl;
}


/*
 Because the Qtextbrowser only support the simple width=**, height=**, not support the 
style="width:**px;height:**px", this function to change the style format.
*/
QString formatStyle(QString sStyle)
{
    QStringList stylelist = sStyle.split(";");
    QRegExp rx("(\\d+)");  // match digit.
    QString s_result;
    foreach(QString st , stylelist)
    {
        int pos=0;
        QString temp;
        QString str = st.toLower();
        while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
            temp=rx.cap(0);
            pos += rx.matchedLength();
        }

        if (str.contains("width"))
        {
            s_result = s_result+ " "+"width="+temp+" ";
        }else if (str.contains("height"))
        {
            s_result = s_result+ " "+"height="+temp+" ";
        }
    }

    return s_result;
}

void showQuestion(QHtmlBrowser *browser, const QString& strHtml, int timeoutSeconds)
{
    browser->showHtml(strHtml, timeoutSeconds);
}

void QHtmlBrowser::showHtml(const QString& strHtml, int timeoutSeconds)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager network;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QByteArray requestContent;
    bool timeout;
    QUrl url(GlobalSetting::getServer());
    QString content = strHtml;

    //QRegExp imgTagRegex("\\<img[^\\>]*src\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"[^\\>]*\\>", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    QRegExp imgTagRegex("\\<img[^\\>]*src\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"[^\\>]*style\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"[^\\>]*\\>", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    imgTagRegex.setMinimal(true);
    QStringList imgSrcList;
    QStringList imgTagList;
    QStringList imgStyleList;
    int offset = 0;
    QString s_test;
    while( (offset = imgTagRegex.indexIn(content, offset)) != -1){
                offset += imgTagRegex.matchedLength();
                imgTagList.append(imgTagRegex.cap(0));
                imgSrcList.append(imgTagRegex.cap(1));
                imgStyleList.append(imgTagRegex.cap(2));
      }

    QString srcUrl;
    //QString resourcePrefix(GlobalSetting::g_server);
    QString ext;
    int index = -1;
    QDateTime stamp;
    foreach(QString src, imgSrcList)
    {
        index++;
        srcUrl.clear();
        if (src.startsWith("http://", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            srcUrl = src;
        else
        {
            if (0){}
                hit_ext(.png);
                hit_ext(.jpeg);
                hit_ext(.jpg);
                hit_ext(.gif);
                hit_ext(.svg);
                else continue;
                if (src.startsWith("://") || src.startsWith("file://", Qt::CaseInsensitive)) continue;
                srcUrl = setUrl(url, src);
                request.setUrl(srcUrl);
                requestContent = srcUrl.toUtf8();
                request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, requestContent.length());
                //QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Md5);
                if (QNetworkReply* reply = network.get(request))
                {
                    timeout = false;
                    stamp = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
                    while (reply->isRunning())
                    {
                        QApplication::processEvents();
                        if (stamp.secsTo(QDateTime::currentDateTime()) > timeoutSeconds)
                        {
                             reply->abort();
                             timeout = true;
                             break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (timeout)
                    {
                         delete reply;
                         continue;
                    }
                    /*
                    // give up crypt the link of image src for speed up the display in embedded system.
                    QString imgFile = resourcePrefix + "/";

                    hash.addData(srcUrl.toUtf8());
                    foreach(char c, hash.result())
                    {
                        int cInt = (int)c;
                        if (cInt < 10)
                            imgFile += "0" + QString::number(cInt, 16).left(1);
                        else
                            imgFile += QString::number(cInt, 16).left(2);
                    }
                    imgFile += ext;
                    */
                    QString target = imgTagList[index];
                    QString style = imgStyleList[index];
                    if(target.contains("style"))
                    {
                        int istart=target.indexOf("style");
                        int iend = target.indexOf(style)+style.size();
                        QString fstyle = target.mid(istart, iend-istart+1);
                        target.replace(fstyle, formatStyle(style));
                    }

                    //target.replace(src, imgFile);
                    target.replace(src, srcUrl);
                    //addResource(imgFile, reply->readAll());
                    addResource(srcUrl, reply->readAll());
                    content.replace(imgTagList[index], target);
                    delete reply;
               }
         }
    }
    addResource(index_tag, content.toUtf8());

    emit loadFinished();
}

void QHtmlBrowser::onLoadFinished()
{
    QTextDocument* document = new QTextDocument(this);
    if (mResources.contains(index_tag))
    {
        foreach(QString key, mResources.keys())
        {
            if (key.startsWith(images_tag))
            {
                document->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource, key, QVariant(mResources[key]));
                //document->adjustSize();

            }
        }
        document->setHtml(QString::fromUtf8(mResources[index_tag]));
        //this->setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(200);
        this->setDocument(document);

    }
}

QHtmlBrowser::QHtmlBrowser(QWidget *parent)
    :QTextBrowser(parent)
{
    this->setReadOnly(true);
    //this->setLineWrapColumnOrWidth();
    this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
    this->setAcceptRichText(true);
    this->setAutoFormatting(QTextEdit::AutoAll);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(loadFinished()), SLOT(onLoadFinished()));
}

QHtmlBrowser::~QHtmlBrowser()
{
}

void QHtmlBrowser::load(const QString &strHtml)
{
    mHtml = strHtml;
    QtConcurrent::run(showQuestion, this, strHtml, 30);
}

void QHtmlBrowser::addResource(const QString &key, const QByteArray &bytes)
{
    if (mResources.contains(key))
        mResources[key] = bytes;
    else
        mResources.insert(key, bytes);
}
```

Follow is sample snapshot show:
[image]